# Filter WooCommerce products by custom attribute object

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woothemes

I just inherited a woocommerce project and I need to change the home page to only show specific brands. They set up a Product-Data => Attribute => pa_brand.

If I print pa_brand array it show me this:

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [term_id] => 1134
        [name] => Name Brand
        [slug] => name-brand
        [term_group] => 0
        [term_taxonomy_id] => 1134
        [taxonomy] => pa_brand
        [description] => 
        [parent] => 0
        [count] => 68
        [object_id] => 3385
        [filter] => raw
    )
)
```

I'm under the impression I would be able to use the pa_brand to filter the query using one of the key value pairs, preferably the slug, but I'm unsure how to do this. None of the examples I've found has an object, just string results:

```
$args = array(
'post_type' => array('product', 'product_variation'),
'posts_per_page' => 3,
'orderby' => 'rand',
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key' => 'pa_brand',
        'value' =>  array('slug' => 'brand-name'),
        'compare' => '=',
    ),
    array(
        'key' => '_stock_status',
        'value' => 'instock',
        'compare' => '='
    )
)
```

);

I've tried a lot of variations on this and none of them work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Woocommerce attributes are Taxonomy,

Assuming you'll create a Brand attribute, the url structure is like this,

`yoursite.com/wp-admin/edit-tags.php?taxonomy=pa_brand&post_type=product`

you see the taxonomy name is `pa_brand`

now if you create a brand say like Honda under that taxonomy, the url is something like this,

`yoursite.com/wp-admin/edit-tags.php?action=edit&taxonomy=pa_brand&tag_ID=6&post_type=product`

Where Honda is a tag under the `pa_brand` taxonomy with tag id 6

Now to have woocommerce query under specific taxonomy,

We can use [WP_query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

we can use an argument like this,

```
$args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'product', 
    'taxonomy' => 'pa_brand', // This is the taxonomy slug for brand taxonomy
    'term' => 'honda' // This is terms slug of the Honda Brand
);
```

If you refer on the docs, the argument above is this same as [this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters)

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'pa_brand',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => 'honda',
        ),
    ),
);
```

EDIT: 
Woocommerce Attributes are taxonomy and not Custom Feilds,

You need to use `tax_query` and not `meta_query`, taxonomies are saved under `wp_term_taxonomy` and `wp_terms` database table, While `meta_query` is for object query based on Meta field/Custom Field value that are save under `wp_postmeta` database table,

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: Do you know how we can check to filter TEXTAREA value, so we need to show all pa_brand attribute where it is not BLANK. Is possible? Please help in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68133985/45261

Comment: Hi @silver it is a custom product attribute, which I have added as TEXTAREA field. And in the tables it is adding data in taxonomy tables, so I think it is taxonomy?