# Filter custom TEXTAREA type attribute NOT EMPTY in WooCommerce product query?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have a custom product attribute name `affiliate_link`, which is a TEXTAREA type field.

In my product query, I want to hide all product which has this field as blank.

For that I have written this in my function.php but it is not working?

```
add_filter('woocommerce_product_query_tax_query', 'custom_product_query_meta_query', 10, 2);
function custom_product_query_meta_query( $tax_query, $query ) {
    
    $taxonomy = 'pa_affiliate_link';

    $tax_query[] = array(
        'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
        'field' => 'name',
        'terms' =>  '',
        'operator' => '!='
    );

   return $tax_query;
}
```

I also tried using this:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_product_query_tax_query', 'custom_product_query_meta_query', 10, 2);
function custom_product_query_meta_query( $tax_query, $query ) {
    
    $taxonomy = 'pa_affiliate_link';

    $tax_query[] = array(
        'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
        'field' => 'name',
        'terms' =>  array(''),
        'operator' => 'NOT IN'
    );

   return $tax_query;
}
```

But above codes are not working and it instead returning all the results, even if it has a blank affiliate_link field.

Please advise how I can fix this?

Comment: Have you tried checking for an empty array instead of empty string?

Comment: yes, I tried with that too, updated code, please check!

Comment: Have you tried filtering a meta query vs a tax query?

Comment: @DubVader no, could you please advise how we can do this?

Comment: You can find a working solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74200775/how-can-i-filter-woocommerce-shop-products-product-loop-by-their-custom-produc

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. May need slight adjustments as I've not tested this, but this is essentially the same as above using meta vs taxonomy.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_product_query_meta_query', 'custom_product_query_meta_query', 10, 2);

function custom_product_query_meta_query( $meta_query, $query ) {

$meta_query[] = array(
        'key'     => 'affiliate_link',
        'value' => '',
        'compare' => '!='
    );

    return $meta_query;

}
```

Comment: I tried but it's not working, could you please advsie?